# Get first capture Image when upload Video in php?

Tags: php

I am trying  to upload video file, it's work fine but I need get first capture image when video file upload successfully. I am trying this way to get image but some times it's not working

```
$tmppath3="services/video/".$cardvideo;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cardvideo']['tmp_name'],$tmppath3))
    {

    $thumb=$date.".jpg";

    $thumbDirectory="services/VideoCapturePic/";
    exec("convert \"{$tmppath3}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 $thumbDirectory$thumb");

    }
```

so any idea please guide me..

Thanks for advance.

Comment: please use punctuations.  I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: ok thanks for advice..so what i am saying is when video file successfully uploading then how can i get first capture image for video.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I should have commented it but, I don't have privilege for that, thats why I'm writting it here:

[This might help](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/447/show-first-frame-as-preview-image)

And you can google for how to use ffmpeg in php..
[This might be one of the useful result](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/)

Comment: i search this links it's nice but is there any another  way to get first capture image for that video

Comment: I have an upload functionality on my site. And i want the php script to take out a random frame from the uploaded video, and save it as an image.

Is that possible?